# Quicksort using only one argument (vector of ints) and first element as pivot

Tags: c++

I need to implement a Quicksort algorithm in C++ which is usually easy but the thing is I can only have the vector as my argument and must choose the first element as pivot. I only have to return the number of comparisons made by my algorithm.
This is my function and this cannot be changed since I have no control over the main.cpp file and only have control over the quicksort.cpp and quicksort.h files.

```
 long long QuickSort(vector<int> & a)
```

Comment: And the question is what exactly?

Comment: `a.begin()` returns an iterator to the first element (or `a.end()` if `a` doesn't contain any elements). `a.front()` accesses the first element directly (check `a.size()` first).

Comment: I am not able to write the code for it. I have tried multiple things but always get stuck when doing the recursion part since I usually have 3 arguments for quicksort but now am stuck with just one argument. @Borgleader

Comment: What are your usual 3 arguments?  `vector<int>` probably has those 3 arguments encapsulated.

Comment: @user3812411 What prevents you from making another function with the signature you need (i.e with 3 arguments) and calling it from a function that has the signature that main requires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing keeps you from making `QuickSort` call a (recursive) helper function.

For example:

```
static long long QuickSortWorker(vector<int> &a, size_t start, size_t length) {
    ...
}

long long QuickSort(vector<int> &a) {
    return QuickSortWorker(a, 0, a.size());
}
```